# How to do you maintain the hair in-between coarse and shampoo-smooth hair?

Tags: hair

My hair basically goes like this: after shampooing and conditioning, it grows in volume and while it feels smooth and silky, it's also a bit lifeless, thick, I run my hands through them and they just fall back to where they were, like a bush or something. I have medium-length hair on top, short on the sides.

Then usually a few days after that, my hair is perfect. It's still a bit smooth and silky, but it's also "firm", with strands and bangs going here and there, and I can style it just by running my hands through it and pushing it in the direction I want.

Then a few days after that, my hair will go completely dead. Lifeless. Dry. Frizzy. So I'll shampoo and condition, and we are back to where we started.

**Question:** How do I maintain the texture my hair has in the middle stage described above?

I don't use products but if it can't be done without, which ones should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, stop washing your hair.
Rinse your hair every day or every other day and let it air dry.

That is all you need.

But do give it a couple of weeks if you are used to washing it with shampoo now.
At first it will feel greasy, or plain dirty, but that is at least half your ideas about it.

Comb (and with long hair brush) it every morning and evening, so the natural oils spread and coat the whole of the hair and do not stick at the roots.
This will take care of dry ends as well.
Then rinsing with lukewarm water (or your normal shower temperature) will get the exess off without soap.

When you need your hair clean after it gets really dirty or when it is washed before cutting, the odd wash with shampoo will not hurt, but if you wash with shampoo for a few times running will lead to having to condition your hair for just rinsing again. (But as you are now used to it, you will not feel dirty anymore.)

Comment: My hair gets oily just days after washing, and yet the ends still get dried out. But how can the excess oil simply disappear with combing and rinsing? I've done that occasionally and it never seemed to work very long.

Comment: Hair gets more oily because you wash it, when you do not wash it (rinsing is OK) it stops making so much oil. Brushing with a good hair brush (less so with a plastic brush) will spread the oil in the hair so all the hair gets as much as it needed.

Comment: You're probably right. I'm quite familiar with the natural-way-of-thinking, however using shampoo and conditioner is an area that I haven't improved in. I think I'll try not using it for a month.

Answer (score 1):

### Natural hair mask

Here is a DIY recipe to condition as well as maintain the healthy sheen of your hair. All you need are two ingredients you can find lying around in your kitchen

- yogurt
- fenugreek seeds (approx 2 tbsp)

Procedure

- Soak the fenugreek seeds overnight.
- Grind the seeds into a fine paste.
- Mix it in with a bowl of yogurt.
- Apply the mask evenly throughout your hair.
- Keep it on for a good hour or so.
- Rinse with lukewarm water.

p.s: Brush out your hair after they dry to get rid of any residual fenugreek seeds.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you just took all the natural oil out of your hair and scalp, and you can take advantage of hair products in this case.

There is a large range of options you can choose from, like hair mousses, oils and pomades.

I would personally suggest using oil, as it is the closest to what our scalp naturally produces. One cheap and natural solutions is coconut oil. Just put a drop or two on the palm of your hands, rub them together and run them through your hair, mostly at the ends.

It will give you the same effects as the 'few days no wash', and keep your hair nice and soft longer.

You can also use it again after a few days if you feel like your hair is too dry.

[Here](http://www.naturallivingideas.com/coconut-oil-for-hair/) you can learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem though my hair is fine (as in the the thickness of each individual strand). I think it is because shampoos can be harsh on the hair due to detergents and foaming agents that are also difficult to completely rinse out. Also, hair dryers can really aggravate and dry your hair out, so if you use one, try to use it on a lower setting or let your hair air-dry naturally (you can set it with rollers or twists/braids if you need to). I've been using milder and sometimes PH balanced shampoos in addition to an Apple Cider Vinegar rinse (mix 9 parts water with one part Apple Cider Vinegar) and my hair is much more manageable nowadays. You can put the rinse in a spray-bottle and saturate your hair or you can just pour it over your hair. You can choose whether you want to rinse it out or not - the smell fades as the hair dries. This rinse conditions and smooths/calms the hair, it also remedy's dandruff. I really don't need a conditioner when I do this either. Afterwards, I just wait until my hair is half dry but still damp, rub some olive oil between my palms to distribute (apply) throughout my hair (concentrating on the driest parts of my hair, such as the ends) to help restore the oil content loss during the shampooing process. During the week, When my hair begins to look limp or dry again after a few days, I dampen it again using a brush wet with water and then apply a tiny bit of olive oil to my ends again; but it is important to wash it within the next few days after that to avoid dirty hair. Good luck.